# EntityFrameworkMUE in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Does anyone know about `EntityFrameworkMUE`? My database IT team sent me this explanation when I asked where my database went.

> We saw in the trace logs (the bottom two lines in the screenshot below) that an Object:Deleted event occurred on the xxxx database executed by EntityFrameworkMUE (the SessionLoginName was username) from HostName yyyyyy.`

Thanks

**Update:** On the HostName where it happened, no one was using the computer when the event happened

Comment: Do you have migrations enabled or disabled?

Comment: Migrations are disabled.

Answer (score 2):

It does not have any significance besides saying that you are actually using Code First. EF decorates your connection string with this token, if going through Code First code path. 
It is supposed to help gather statistical data about EF usage on SQL Azure (i.e. what percentage of customers use Code First v. Designer). 
Due to little value and some problems associated with it, the feature is going away in EF6.

Here is some additional context:
http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/38

Thanks,
Maurycy

Comment: What would explain the database deletion then?

Comment: Did you make any changes to your model? Database could be deleted (and attempted to be recreated) if you use DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges initializer, for instance. If you haven't made any changes, and using DropCreateDatabaseAlways, this would also happen. Those are the likely culprits, given that the connection string has EntityFrameworkMUE token attached.

Comment: Thanks. Are these culprits documented somewhere?

Comment: I am not using the ones you mentioned. Are these two the only ones?

Comment: There are two more initializers that shipped with Entity Framework: CreateDatabaseIfNotExixts (default), and MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion (migrations-related). Neither of them drops the database though.

Comment: Here is a good post on how to use initializers with EF: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm 
If you are intested in inner workings of initializers, here is a blog of one of EF developers, where he describes initialization process in great detail: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/04/15/code-first-inside-dbcontext-initialization/